# How to validate JSON in Shopify Liquid templates in VS Code?

Tags: shopify, eslint, liquid, shopify-template

Recently there was a bug caused by a missing comma below inside a Shopify Liquid template:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    ...
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Content"
      }
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "title",
        "label": "Title"
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Is there a way to automatically show that red squiggly line in VS Code to indicate that the JSON is malformed? I tried adding this to my user settings but no luck:

```
    "eslint.validate": [
      "javascript",
      "javascriptreact",
      { "language": "liquid" }
    ]
```

I have the ESLint and Liquid (Neil Ding) extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has some tools for that, you should install [theme check and shopify cli](https://shopify.dev/themes/tools/theme-check/vscode)

Comment: Installing this extension generated a thousand errors and warnings, but none of it was for malformed JSON inside a Liquid template :(.